# matplotlib.pyplot.hist behaving weirdly

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

So I've been trying to use the below code to plot histograms of numpy arrays, except matplotlib.pyplot.hist starts giving me output that I don't really understand after I've modified the numpy array that I initially plotted. I've attached links to both images below and any help would be appreciated.

P.S. mat is a numpy array containing pixel values of a grayscale image.

```
def plot_histogram(mat):
   v = mat.flatten()

   plt.hist(v, 256, [0, 256], histtype = 'step')
   plt.show()
```

[Plain Image Hist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EILIN.png)
[Modified Image Hist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay3F9.png)

Comment: It is very unclear which data and which code led to your second image.  When working with discrete data, a histogram needs explicit bin boundaries around those discrete values. For example setting them at the halves: `plt.hist(v, bins=np.arange(-0.5, 256), histtype='step')`

Comment: Hi, I tried your edit @JohanC but that doesn't seem to be the problem. Also is there any more info that I can add to make the query clearer? (This is my first question on stackoverflow)

Comment: Can you post a slice of sample data, e.g. the value of `v[:10]`?

Comment: No, @JohanC I'm using matplotlib: 3.3.4. And its pixel values so basically in the range 0-255

Comment: Please try to install the latest version (`pip install matplotlib --upgrade)`. Also try to restart your environment and create a simple reproducible example. Your second image gives the impression that it is created with a `for`-loop, maybe s: plot_histogram(np.array([i])`??? So, please show more of your code.

Comment: It was because of the for loop.  `mat.flatten()` was returns a 2D array. I changed  ` plt.hist(v, 256, [0, 256], histtype = 'step')` to ` plt.hist(np.ravel(mat), 256, [0, 256], histtype = 'step')` and it's working now. Thanks a lot for taking the time to help.

Comment: @mg4603 I am glad you sorted this out.  Can you please post your comment as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Due to using a for loop to modify the image

```
mat.flatten()
```

returns a 2D array
Changing

```
plt.hist(v, 256, [0, 256], histtype = 'step')
```

to

```
plt.hist(np.ravel(mat), 256, [0, 256], histtype = 'step')
```

solves the problem.